# How can I change the font size for headings and page numbers in the table of contents?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script, scrartcl

I managed to customize the formatting of the font for the TOC entries for the sections in my document.

How can I set the formatting of the levels below section with scrartcl's (KOMA's) help? Is this even possible or do I need to use a package like `tocloft`?

(Sidenote: using the uncommented `\footnotesize` in the document leads to only the text being set in that font size, no the page numbers.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{multicol}


\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\footnotesize}
\addtokomafont{sectionentrydots}{\footnotesize}
\addtokomafont{sectionentrypagenumber}{\footnotesize}
%\addtokomafont{subsectionentry}{\footnotesize}
%\addtokomafont{subsectionentrydots}{\footnotesize}
%\addtokomafont{subsectionentrypagenumber}{\footnotesize}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
%\footnotesize
\tableofcontents
%\normalsize

\section{AAAAAAAA}
\subsection{aaaaaaa}
\subsection{bbbbbb}

\section{BBBBB}
\subsection{cccccccccc}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{e}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\RedeclareSectionCommands`:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentryformat=\footnotesize,
  toclinefill=\footnotesize\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  tocpagenumberformat=\footnotesize
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
%11pt,% default
%a4paper,% default
sectionentrydots% enable dots for section entries
]
{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed for older TeX distributions
%\pdfgentounicode=1% not needed in the example
\usepackage{multicol}

\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\footnotesize}
\addtokomafont{sectionentrydots}{\footnotesize}% option sectionentrydots is needed to enable the dots
\addtokomafont{sectionentrypagenumber}{\footnotesize}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentryformat=\footnotesize,
  toclinefill=\footnotesize\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  tocpagenumberformat=\footnotesize
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{AAAAAAAA}
  \subsection{aaaaaaa}
  \subsection{bbbbbb}
  \section{BBBBB}
  \subsection{cccccccccc}
  \subsection{d}
  \subsection{e}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark

```latex
\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\footnotesize}
\addtokomafont{sectionentrydots}{\footnotesize}% option sectionentrydots is needed to enable the dots
\addtokomafont{sectionentrypagenumber}{\footnotesize}
```

is equivalent to

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\footnotesize,
  toclinefill=\footnotesize\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\footnotesize
]{section}
```

The second version works without option `sectionentrydots`.

Comment: Wow! This is one impressive answer with so much detailed knowledge about the class! Thank you. :) I certainly would not have reached the same solution with KOMA's abilities. Can say I stumbled upon `pagenumberformat` only though but I did not succeed to make use of it.

Comment: An addendum: your code alone somehow did not produce the same neat vertical spacing (which I also was looking for). I had to add `tocbeforeskip=3pt,` to the section-related command `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on an alternative way in the meantime, using `tocloft`:

## Picture

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\footnotesize\sffamily}

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{-2pt}}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-1pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\tableofcontents

\section{AAAAAAAA}
\subsection{aaaaaaa}
\subsection{bbbbbb}

\section{BBBBB}
\subsection{cccccccccc}
\subsection{d}
\subsection{e}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```